# Cut off file_get_contents if it takes too long

Tags: php

I use the freeGeoIP service to track who is visiting my website into my own database.  Sometimes it takes a while to retrieve the data.  Is there anyway that I can cut off the retrieval of the data if it is taking too long?

Here is my code:

`$geoIP = @file_get_contents("http://freegeoip.net/csv/{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}");`

`

Comment: Any objection to using `cURL()`? It's much better and supports this feature

Comment: I'm not opposed to it, Can you give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a context an sent with it a timeout (reference: [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents#108309))

Excerpt:

```
$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => "Content-Type: text/xml\r\n".
      "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("$https_user:$https_password")."\r\n",
    'content' => $body,
    'timeout' => 60
  )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$url = 'https://'.$https_server;
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context, -1, 40000);
```

In your case this should roughly translate to (untested):

```
$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'method'  => 'GET',
    'header'  => "Content-Type: text/csv",
    'content' => '',
    'timeout' => 10
  )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$url = "http://freegeoip.net/csv/{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}";
$geoip = file_get_contents($url, false, $context, -1, 40000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fork the program execution: [How to fork with PHP (4 different approaches)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/22919/how-to-fork-with-php-4-different-approaches).

Documentation about the PNCL functions (including fork) can be found in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pcntl.php).